# Resource Manager cannot distinguish case-sensitive strings from resx file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unicode, embedded-resource, resx

Please help I write a resx file for translation of my project (from Vietnamese, to be specific).

I can add these new resources successfully

```
var firstNode = new ResXDataNode("Â", value1);
resxWriter.AddResource(firstNode);
var secondNode = new ResXDataNode("â", value2);
resxWriter.AddResource(secondNode);
```

But after that I cannot read resx file by "Managed Resource Editor" of Visual Studio normally (it can still be edited by XML editor) `Error: There is another key with same value` ? 2 entries with key and value are added in XML file (when check with other XML editor / or notepad ..).

The question is, the `resourceManager.GetString("Â")` (or the other key `"â"`) could not retrieve the value for the key provided?
How can I get the unicode sensitive key string from resx?
Is there any other way around this ?

UPDATE:

I just discovered that the problem persists even when I change `"Â"` => `"A"` and `"â"` => `"a"` ==> It seems that resx file insensitive to case ==> How can I fix this?

UPDATE 2:

For those who encounter the same problem as me ==> resx is not case sensitive ==> resx usage instructs to not use same key with different case letters.

For my project, I changed to i18n Nuget package because IViewLocaliser and IStringLocaliser only available for .Net Core MVC (or MVC >= 6). Also I change from using resx file to .po/ .pot file which is more convenient for translation.

Hope I can help !!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the offical documentation on how to use resx files? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically

Comment: What is the type of your project? Winforms? WPF? Or any other? If is a Winform, to "translate project", you can try to set form's `Localizable` to true and select the language you want in `Language`.

Comment: @Kyle Wang My project is a MVC 5 .NET . Oh I just discovered that the resx is insensitive to case, even "A" and "a" can cause similar problem

Comment: @Pete I read that doc from Microsoft many times but there is nothing mentioning about the problem I had.